# Get dynamic values from JSON for Drop-down list

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsfiddle

There is  drop down list of subjects and I have hard coded them in `IF condition`. I'm trying to dynamically get values from JSON to drop-down list ?

```
   function testMessage(){
       var mysel = $("#sub_select option:selected" ).text()
       console.log(mysel); 
       if($( "#sub_select option:selected" ).text() == "Maths"){
             for (var i = 0; i < data[0].Grades.length; i++) { 
                $('#grade_select').append('<option>'+data[0].Grades[i]+'</option>');  
            } 
        }      
       else if($( "#sub_select option:selected" ).text()=="Chemistry"){
           $('#grade_select option').remove();
            for (var i = 0; i < data[1].Grades.length; i++) { 
                $('#grade_select').append('<option>'+data[1].Grades[i]+'</option>');  
            } 
        }
    }
```

Please open this Fiddle below:

http://jsfiddle.net/pjxhk10u/

Comment: What do you want to do exactly ?

Comment: Question is not very clear, your code seems to be working in JSFiddle.

Comment: You need to make an AJAX call on dropdown change function to get the data from server. Search dependant dropdown on google and there are plenty of examples available.

Comment: I think you've missed `$('#grade_select option').remove();` in `if` condition of `"Maths"` maybe that why you have incorrect drop down values?

Comment: Code is working, but look at the if conditions, They are hard coded, If another subject like biology or history is added, my code won't work. So, is there any way to remove this hard coding..   `$( "#sub_select option:selected" ).text() == "Maths")`

Comment: @shrys I want to remove that "Maths, chemistry", those values should not be hard coded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to generalize you need a way to get the `x` in `data[x]` besides checking what `$("#sub_select option:selected").text()` equals. One solution is to add a `dataIndex="i"` attribute to each option element.

Change

```
$('#sub_select').append('<option id='+data[i].Subject+'>'+data[i].Subject+'</option>');
```

to

```
$('#sub_select').append('<option dataIndex="'+i+'" id='+data[i].Subject+'>'+data[i].Subject+'</option>');
```

Then we can replace the hard coded if statements with a generalization.

Change

```
if($( "#sub_select option:selected" ).text() == "Maths"){
  for (var i = 0; i < data[0].Grades.length; i++) { 
    $('#grade_select').append('<option>'+data[0].Grades[i]+'</option>');  
  } 
}      
else if($( "#sub_select option:selected" ).text()=="Chemistry"){
  $('#grade_select option').remove();
  for (var i = 0; i < data[1].Grades.length; i++) { 
    $('#grade_select').append('<option>'+data[1].Grades[i]+'</option>');  
  } 
}
```

to

```
const selectedOption = $('#sub_select option:selected');
const dataIndex = selectedOption.attr('dataIndex');
$('#grade_select option').remove();
for (var i = 0; i < data[dataIndex].Grades.length; i++) { 
  $('#grade_select').append('<option>'+data[dataIndex].Grades[i]+'</option>');  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to get data of the subject and use it to bind it to your drop down:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var data = [{
    "Grades": ["3", "2", "1", "7", "6", "5", "4", "9", "8", "10"],
    "Subject": "Maths"
  }, {
    "Grades": ["9", "10"],
    "Subject": "Chemistry"
  }];

  console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    $('#sub_select').append('<option id=' + data[i].Subject + '>' + data[i].Subject + '</option>');
  }
  $('#sub_select').on('change', testMessage);

  function testMessage() {
    var mysel = $("#sub_select option:selected").text();
    console.log(mysel);
    var dropDownData = data.find(function (element) { return element.Subject == mysel });

    $('#grade_select').append('<option>Grades...</option>');
    if (dropDownData != null) {
      $('#grade_select option').remove();
      for (var i = 0; i < dropDownData.Grades.length; i++) {
        $('#grade_select').append('<option>' + dropDownData.Grades[i] + '</option>');
      }
    }
  }

  $.each(data, function(i, option) {
    $('#sel').append($('<option/>').attr("value", option.subjectValue).text(option.subjectGrade));
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="mongoreport" method='POST'>
  <select id="sub_select" name="selsub" value="subjectValue">
    <option>Subjects...</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <select id="grade_select" name="selgrade" value="subjectGrade">
    <option>Grades...</option>
  </select>
  <input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add remove on select option grade
please check updated on your jsfiddle link 
http://jsfiddle.net/pjxhk10u/

```
var data = [{"Grades":["3","2","1","7","6","5","4","9","8","10"],"Subject":"Maths"},{"Grades":["9","10"],"Subject":"Chemistry"}];

    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
        $('#sub_select').append('<option id='+data[i].Subject+'>'+data[i].Subject+'</option>');  
    }
       $('#sub_select').on('change',testMessage);   

       function testMessage(){
           var mysel = $("#sub_select option:selected" ).text()
           console.log(mysel); 
           if($( "#sub_select option:selected" ).text() == "Maths"){
          $('#grade_select option').remove(); // add this

                 for (var i = 0; i < data[0].Grades.length; i++) { 
                    $('#grade_select').append('<option>'+data[0].Grades[i]+'</option>');  
                } 

            }      
           else if($( "#sub_select option:selected" ).text()=="Chemistry"){
               $('#grade_select option').remove();
                for (var i = 0; i < data[1].Grades.length; i++) { 
                    $('#grade_select').append('<option>'+data[1].Grades[i]+'</option>');  
                } 
            }
        }

     $.each(data, function(i, option) {
            $('#sel').append($('<option/>').attr("value", option.subjectValue).text(option.subjectGrade));
        });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your JSFiddle with the code which will work perfect for you. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bpu359g0/)

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    var data = [
     {"Grades":["3","2","1","7","6","5","4","9","8","10"],"Subject":"Maths"},
     {"Grades":["9","10"],"Subject":"Chemistry"}];

  var subGrade = {};
  $.each(data, function(index, value) {
      $.each(value, function(k, v){
          subGrade[value["Subject"]] = value["Grades"];
      })
  })

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
          $('#sub_select').append('<option id='+data[i].Subject+'>'+data[i].Subject+'</option>');  
    }

    $('#sub_select').on('change',testMessage);  

    function testMessage(){
        var mysel = $("#sub_select" ).val();    
        if (subGrade.hasOwnProperty(mysel)) {
            $('#grade_select option').remove();
            var options = subGrade[mysel];
            for (var i=0; i<options.length; i++) {
                $('#grade_select').append('<option>'+options[i]+'</option>');
            }
        }
    }   
})
```